# Wso2 Carbon application build missing artifact

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to build my car application but when trying to install the dependencies i get this error

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.axis2:mex:jar:1.6.1 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/)
```

It says that it cant find this dependency but it does exist in http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/axis2/mex/1.6.1-wso2v11/

What should i do to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Mex is not a `jar`. It's of type `mar`. Therefore you need to specify the dependency type at the pom. Refer how it is done [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/blob/ed28141af150914bb24e83b349aaa1eaa082cbb1/modules/distribution/pom.xml#L125-L130).